# build a v-checkbox list in Vue

Tags: vue.js

I need to build a to-do list with check boxes but instead of using an array that pulls each items as if it was a separate row these are all separate columns. So the object looks like

```
     [{"InterProgramatic":false,"IntraProgramatic":false,"MultiInstitution":false,"Accepted":true,"Rejected":false,"Cancer_Related":true}]
```

How can I build the Checkboxes using a v-for loop?

my array is simply

```
    statusItems: []
```

If each item was in a separate row then I can assign a separate id, but is there an easier way to do this in Vue?  To save the data I planned on just sending back to the Web API the statusItems object and parsing it there so I was hoping to bind it if possible.

I can use

```
      v-for="(item, index) in statusItems" :key="index" 

           <v-checkbox
                :key="index"
                :label="item"
                color="success"
                v-bind:id="status"
                v-model="statusItems[key].checked"
                @change="statusChange(statusItems[key])"
              >></v-checkbox>
```

to build the checkboxes but not sure how to bind it.  Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Is that what your trying to do ?
https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-tkx60?fontsize=14

To bind the `v-model`, you need to use the array index or the object key.

Comment: Great work and I truly appreciate it.  One question the check-boxes are not checked and do not check but the label says that it is.  Is this something in the dependencies that they use? or something in your awesome code-- smile

Comment: Yeah i got a problem to import material icons, i did not took the time to debug this. (but you can see the color changes slightly)

Comment: Thanks  - I'll play with it

Comment: Glad it helped.